# ${} not working in jsp spring project

Tags: spring-mvc

In my dynamic web project with Spring MVC framework ${} is not showing variable value in jsp page.

Please find below code:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SpringMVCTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>

    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springtutorial.basecontroller" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

**BaseController.java** controller class

```
package com.springtutorial.basecontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller

public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printHello(){
        return new ModelAndView("index", "message", "Hi"); 
    }

}
```

**index.jsp** it is the only jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Spring MVC Framework</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>learning</h1>
    <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to Spring MVC framework, just started learning it. I just checked on internet for the code and it is almost similar, but still no luck.

Please let me know if i am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made changes in BaseController.java file and dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

**BaseController.java**

```
package com.springtutorial.basecontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
//import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
//import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller

public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hi");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springtutorial.basecontroller" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

Please try with this. It is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing this issue need the check for

1. Is web.xml  declared as 2.4 or higher, in the above case it is using 3.1 . So this is not the case

2.Use isELIgnored="false" in page directive.

```
    <%@ page language="java" 
    contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
    isELIgnored="false" 
    pageEncoding="UTF8"%>
```